# Javascript - How to find the closest number (with working example)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do a code that calculates what is the next session based on an array of sessions.
***All dates that already passed the end date should be ignored***. I think I am near a solution but I don't know how to finish this...

```js
const sessions = [{
    "end": "2022-12-28T06:15:00Z",
    "start": "2022-12-23T06:00:00Z" // This should be the next session because 2022-12-23T06:00:00Z is closer to now than 2022-12-31T06:00:00Z (last entry)
  },
  {
    "end": "2022-12-20T06:00:00Z", // This date already passed (Today is 21st December)
    "start": "2022-12-18T06:00:00Z"
  },
  {
    "end": "2023-01-26T06:00:00Z",
    "start": "2022-12-31T06:00:00Z"
  }
];

const nextSession = {};

sessions.forEach(session => {
  const sessionStart = new Date(session.start).getTime();
  const sessionEnd = new Date(session.end).getTime();
  const now = new Date().getTime();
  // Calculate the difference between now and the session start
  const diffStartTime = sessionStart - now;
  console.log('Diff Start: ' + diffStartTime);
  // Calculate the difference between now and the session end
  const diffEndTime = sessionEnd - now;
  console.log('Diff End: ' + diffEndTime);

  // TODO how to get the next session?
});
```

Any help?

Comment: You can do this in O(n) complexity by going over all the sessions and keeping track of the nearest (so where start diff is the lowest positive, so ignore negative values) and return it in the end.

Comment: @rowan-vr the sessions will not be that big of an array. Like 100 entries maximum I think

Comment: The main thing you are missing is some bookkeeping to keep track of the nearest (in the future), you can do so by comparing it with nextSession and storing it in nextSession if it's closer than the current nextSession

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with a two-step approach. First filter out all expired sessions and then sort that the most recent session (according to the start) is in the first element

```js
const sessions = [{
    "end": "2022-12-28T06:15:00Z",
    "start": "2022-12-23T06:00:00Z" // This should be the next session because 2022-12-23T06:00:00Z is closer to now than 2022-12-31T06:00:00Z (last entry)
  },
  {
    "end": "2022-12-20T06:00:00Z", // This date already passed (Today is 21st December)
    "start": "2022-12-18T06:00:00Z"
  },
  {
    "end": "2023-01-26T06:00:00Z",
    "start": "2022-12-31T06:00:00Z"
  }
  ];

const filteredSessions = sessions
               .filter(item => new Date(item.end) > new Date())
               .sort((a,b) => new Date(a.start) - new Date(b.start))

if (filteredSessions.length) console.log(filteredSessions[0])
```

Comment: Maybe this is a better solution

Comment: Sorting is more expensive than going over the entire array once, for this specific application it probably does not matter, but when having a lot of sessions it could make a difference. This solution would have a complexity of O(nlogn) whilst going over the array once is O(n). It is just unneccessary to sort when you only want the minimal element

Comment: the above solution has the charme that all upcoming sessions would be in order.... if it is only for the very next session, a `reduce`- or `apply` function to find the "minimum"-start date would also be fine